# Create CBitmap object from memory

Tags: windows, visual-c++, bitmap

I have a memory block which is merely binary data read from a .jpeg file. How can i create a CBitmap object from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API or standard library function that deals with JPEGs. However, you may use GDI+ routuines  to read the JPEG data and translate it to a bitmap, around which you would construct a CBitmap object.